# how to count the occurence of a word in multiple rows of a mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, instances

i am looking for some help with counting the number of occurences in multiple rows of a mysql db.the purpose is for creting a search engine  like google but only for my website

the scheme is to display the entry which has the most number of occurences of the word at the very top

for eg . the user searches for the word key.the records are searched and the data is shown in order of the number of occurences

```
 1.this is a key which is a test key and also the profile key (3 occurences)
 2.key give me a key (2 occurences)
 ....and so on...
```

is this the best approach?

```
SELECT (LENGTH(daya) - LENGTH(REPLACE(data, 'key', ''))) / LENGTH('key') AS `count` ORDER BY `count` DESC // data is the column name and key is the word
```

or is there a better one

**Note:**i dont want to use `Like % %`. also i want to show the number of times the word has occured like so `the word key has occured 3 times`.Could i use `count()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the count in `ORDER BY` clause.

Try  this way:

```
SELECT *,(LENGTH(data) - LENGTH(REPLACE(data, 'key', ''))) / LENGTH('key') as cnt
FROM TableName
ORDER BY ((LENGTH(data) - LENGTH(REPLACE(data, 'key', ''))) / LENGTH('key')) DESC
```

To get the records of 2 occurences, you can use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT *,(LENGTH(data) - LENGTH(REPLACE(data, 'key', ''))) / LENGTH('key') as cnt
FROM TableName
HAVING cnt=2
ORDER BY ((LENGTH(data) - LENGTH(REPLACE(data, 'key', ''))) / LENGTH('key')) DESC
```

Comment: and what about counting it to show `key is occured 2 times`

Comment: no i mean can i use `count()` to show key has been use 2 times?

Comment: @Mr.coder: You can use `HAVING` clause for that. See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine, but you can dispense with the division by using one character more or less:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(REPLACE(data, 'key', 'key1')) - LENGTH(data)) as `count`
FROM table t
ORDER BY `count` DESC // data is the column name and key is the word
```

If you want values that appear "n" times, using can use the `having` clause in MySQL:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(REPLACE(data, 'key', 'key1')) - LENGTH(data)) as `count`
FROM table t
HAVING `count` = 2
ORDER BY `count` DESC // data is the column name and key is the word
```

This use of the `having` clause is a MySQL extension and will not work in other databases.