# how to match for a hash tag using mysqli regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli

since i could not understand much of the answers given to my previous question (**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711851/how-to-count-the-occurence-of-a-word-in-multiple-rows-of-a-mysql-db)**),i was forced to do an extensive google search on mysqli and hashtags and i appear to have found a solution as the below code

**THE CODE**

```
$count_hash = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE colummname  REGEXP '[[:<:]][[:>:]]'")or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
```

**my question**

suppose i have the following structure

```
id|text          |
1 | search engine|
2 | search       |
```

and suppose the user enters the query #search the query is supposed to find the posts that have the text #search in it and count them then show the count

**the problem** : i dont know how do i use it meaning ive got errors with everything ive tried

**what ive tried**

```
....REGEXP '[[:<:]].$query.[[:>:]]'.....
```

Comment: remove the # then `select ..LIKE '%$query%'` would work fine in the example above

Comment: @Dagon ive tried `LIKE '%$query%'` but didnt work as expected

Comment: if every thing above is correct, it would return both id 1 and 2

Comment: @Dagon that it does but the problem is in the count it shows 3 instead of 2 when the word search is entered

Comment: something like: ?`$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);`

Comment: @Dagon im sorry but i forgot that i need to show the number of times the word was used in the entire database

Comment: do you only want the count? or to return the rows as well?

Comment: @Dagon no just the count

Comment: `select count(id) as TOTAL from foo
where term LIKE '%search%'`
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3c2b/1/0

Comment: @Dagon ok and what about a hash tag???

Comment: remove it before the search in php `$query=str_replace('#','',$query);`

Comment: @Dagon ok will try that how about you post this in the form of a answer so that i can vote you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly remove the # from the query like so:

```
$query=str_replace('#','',$query);
```

then query the db:

```
select count(id) as TOTAL from foo where term LIKE '%$query%'
```

Demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3c2b/1/0

plan B, do it all in mysql:

```
select count(id) as TOTAL from foo
where term LIKE REPLACE("%#$query%","#","")
```

DEmo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/650137/1/0

Comment: i tried your query and it think thats not what im looking for i meant what if the user searches for #search how to match it using regex

Comment: should be $query not search, as in a variable. hope that's clear